# Complex probability

Tags: probability

I have a card deck with 4 Qs, 8 Rs, 8 Bs, 8 Ns and 16 Ps.

What is the probability to pick up a concrete combination of 5 cards? Is there a simple formula that do not forces me to build trees?

E.g.
What is the probability of having QRRPP, RBNNP? 
The order does not matter, thus QBBNN = BNBNQ.

I am handling smaller examples. But for this I kind of struggled to understand if my thought process is correct. Does the same logic apply to combinations of less cards, eg 4 or 2?

Comment: I could find find examples with less different values like 2 colors. They are building trees. It is obvious that here a three will be really complex. Is there a formulato calculate it in constant time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability on e.g. QRRPP is:$$\frac{\binom41\binom82\binom80\binom80\binom{16}2}{\binom{44}5}$$

The order of the factors in the numerator corresponds with order QRBNP.

E.g.  the second factor $\binom82$ in the numerator is the number of ways to select $2$ R's out of $8$ R's, and e.g. the fourth factor $\binom80$ in the numerator is the number of ways to select $0$ N's out of $8$ N's.

We are dealing with a multivariate hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!